# Desktop login not allowed

Tags: login, lightdm

Suddenly my `Odroid` mini PC with `Ubuntu` do not allow to login to Desktop. After I press `Log In` screen flashes with dark for one second and gets back without logged in.

I found error in `/var/log/auth.log` file:

```
odroid pan_succeed_if (lightdn:auth): requirement “user ingroup nopassudlogin” was met by user “odroid” "var/log/auth.log” [readonly] 812L, 76963C
```

I tried to remove line below in file `/etc/pam.d/lightdm`

```
auth sufficient pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup nopassudlogin
```

This allowed to enter password at desktop login, but still can't login.

I also found lines kin syslog:

```
Error reading existing Xauthority: Failed to open file "/home/odroid/.Xauthority": Permission denied 
Error writing X authority: Failed to open X authority /home/odroid/.Xauthority: Permission denied
```

How to understand what is really going on there and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems like caused by an unmounted encrypted home folder, maybe because you have recently changed your password.

if you have encrypted your home folder.
I recommend this fix : log onn Tty1 with your username and new password
then enter this command : ecryptfs-mount-private + hit enter
then you're gonna be asked to enter your passphrase, so enter your old password this time.
remember: log in using your new password but when it asks for passphrase enter your old password. this should mount your home folder and fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved by deleting old and creating new .Xauthority file

Comment: How you arrived at this solution would be a good thing to add to this answer.